¿Como Puedo Agregar Una Primary Key a 1 Modelo de Datos en VB.NET?
Estoy Haciendo una Aplicacion en VB.Net y .Net Core MVC y He Agregado 1 Modelo de Datos Con una Clase Usuarios:
Public Class Usuarios

    Public Id As Integer
    Public Nombre As String
    Public Clave As String
    Public FechaAlta As DateTime
    Public Comunidad As String
    Public comunidades As SelectListItem
    Public Ciudad As String
    Public Rol As Integer

End Class

Al ir a Hacer el Scafolding para que Cree las Vistas y el Controlador me da este Error:

¿Alguien Sabe como Solucionarlo?
Ya He Probado Bastantes Cosas y no me Ha Funcionado Nada
Saludos
